# undefined object exception(propTypes Array)

Tags: react-native

My program running correctly on an iOS emulator but it throws an `undefined object` exception when I run it on my Android device. It says `item.peopleGroup.length undefined object(propTypes Array)`. Why is it running correctly in iOS but throwing an exception in Android? `peopleGroup` is an `ArrayObject` indeed.

```
render() {
    const item = this.props.current_event_item.event;
    return (
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.peopleGroup.length} people are going . 3 spots left</Text>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
            <PeopleGroupView peopleGroup={item.peopleGroup} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

[image: error message]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant code and the error you get. Preferably with a call stack of the exception.

Comment: the screenshot seems is made for blind people, it's hard to look it at

Answer (score 0):

I might found the cause of this problem now. My program was created through the Expo. I usually create debug and test the program on that Expo platform and it usually be a good development tool. However I guess it might have some bugs as well. Because the application except undefined object exception if I running it locally, however, it running correctly after I package and upload it to the Expo server. Therefore, package process might fix some of bugs I guess.